# Trying to get the Average Execution Time of a function, but the recorded value ends up as 0

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to get the average execution time of a function, but whenever I get a single lap of the function in, the recorded time ends up being 0. Even after calling the function 100 times, the recorded execution time for each call is 0. Is there something missing in my code to get the execution time of this function?

Driver.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "generateSuffixArray.c"
#include "selectionsort.c"
void DataReset(int A[], int B[], int n){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        B[i] = A[i];
    }
}

double getAverage(double Laps[], int iterations)
{
    int j;
    double sum = 0.0, Average;
    for(j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
    {
        sum+=Laps[j];
    } 
    Average = sum/iterations;
    
    return Average;
}

void main(){
    int n = 10, k = 100, i, j;
    double elapsed;
    double Laps[k];
    char String[n+1];
    int indices[n];
    int copy[n];
    clock_t start, end;
    
    memset(String, '\0', sizeof(String));
    generateSuffixArray(n, indices, String);
    DataReset(indices, copy, n);
    
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < k; j++){
            start = clock();
            if(i == 0){
                if(j == 0){
                    printf("------Selection Sort------\n"); 
                }
                startSS(n, indices, String);
            }
            end = clock();
            DataReset(copy, indices, n);
            elapsed = ((double) (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
            elapsed *= 1000;
            Laps[j] = elapsed;
            
            printf("MET = %1f\n", elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

generateSuffixArray.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// --- Print Function to test array content ---//
/*void printSuffixes(int N, int SArray[], char String[]){
    int i;
    printf("%s\n", String);
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("%d", SArray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}*/

// --- From alphabet {a, c, g, t} --- //
void generateSuffixArray(int N, int SArray[], char String[])
{
    int i, charNo;
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        charNo = rand() % (4 - 1 + 1) + 1;
        switch(charNo){
            case 1: String[i] = 'a';
            break;
            case 2: String[i] = 'c';
            break;
            case 3: String[i] = 'g';
            break;
            case 4: String[i] = 't';
            break;
            default: charNo = rand() % (4 - 1 + 1) + 1;
                    i--;
        }
        SArray[i] = i;
    }
    //printSuffixes(N, SArray, String);
}
```

selectionsort.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void switcher(int *xp, int *yp){
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
 
void selectionSort(int n, int indices[], char arr[]){
    int i, j, min_idx, curr_idx, key_idx;
    char key[n], temp[n];
    
    // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array
        key_idx = indices[i];
        strncpy(key, arr + indices[i], strlen(arr) - indices[i]);
        key[strlen(key)+1] = '\0';
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++){
            strncpy(temp, arr + indices[j], strlen(arr) - indices[i]);
            temp[strlen(temp)+1] = '\0';
            if(strcmp(key, temp) < 0){  
                min_idx = j;
                strncpy(key, arr + indices[j], strlen(arr) - indices[j]);
                key[strlen(key)+1] = '\0';
            }
        }
        // Swap the found minimum element with the first element
        switcher(&indices[min_idx], &indices[i]);
    }
   
}
 /* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
// --- Function to print the sorted array --- // 
void printArray(int size, int arr[]){
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
}
 
// --- Start of Insertion Sort process --- //
int startSS(int n, int indices[], char arr[]){
    selectionSort(n, indices, arr);
    //printArray(n, indices);
}
```

Comment: `clock()` is a pretty blunt tool for execution timing. You should time events that last at least one second. You seem to be timing *each* of the 100 events, not the total (of each requiring a sort, not already sorted data). Aside: why the `1` in `%1f`? Is that a typo of `%lf`?

Comment: I'm actually required to time each execution of the function. And, now that I look at it, yeah the 1 in %1f is a typo. I meant it to be %lf for the double.

Comment: Sort a much larger list of items then. Consider the granularity of `clock`.

Comment: Okay then, looks like that worked. and it looks like it's gonna take some time to get the time for each call of the function. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: regarding: `#include "generateSuffixArray.c" and `#include "selectionsort.c"`  DO not include *.c files,  Rather link the files together and write appropriate header files and include the header files

Comment: regarding: `key[strlen(key)+1] = '\0';`  the function: `strlen()` uses the NUL termination byte to find the length of a char array.  so this will not work

Comment: regarding: `void main(){`  There are only two valid signatures for`main()` They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char* argv[] )`

Comment: It seems to crash at n = 1000000 though